# Generating Interdependent Data in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to compute a column in SAS, that has dependency on itself. For example, I have the following list of initial values

```
    ID Var_X Var_Y Var_Z
     1     2     3     .   
     2     .     2     .
     3     .     .     .
     4     .     .     .
     5     .     .     .
     6     .     .     .
     7     .     .     .
```

I need to fill up the blank spaces. The formulae are as follows:

```
    Var_Z = 0.1 + 4*Var_x + 5*Var_Y
    Var_X = lag1(Var_Z)
    Var_Y = lag2(Var_Z)
```

As we see values of Var_X, Var_Y and Var_Z are inter-dependent. So the computaion needs to follow an specific order.

```
First we compute when ID = 1, Var_Z = 0.1 + 4*2 + 5*3 = 23.1
Next, when ID = 2,  Var_X = lag1(Var_Z) = 23.1
```

Var_Y does not need computation at ID = 2 as we already have the initial value here. So, we have

```
    ID Var_X Var_Y Var_Z
     1     2     3  23.1   
     2   23.1    2  102.5 (= 0.1 + 4*23.1 +5*2)
     3     .     .     .
     4     .     .     .
     5     .     .     .
     6     .     .     .
     7     .     .     .
```

We keep repeating this procedure until all vaues are calculated.

Is there a way, SAS can handle this? I tried DO loop, but I guess I did not do a good job coding it right. It just stops after ID = 2.

I am new at SAS so not familiar if there is a way SAS can handle this easily. Will wait for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use LAG or RETAIN, if you're just doing this in a single data step.  DO loop by itself will handle things nicely.  RETAIN would only be needed if we were doing something involving a pre-existing data set, but there's really no reason to use one.

I'm using a shortcut here - while you describe VAR_Y in terms of VAR_Z, you really mean that after one iteration, VAR_Z moves to VAR_X and VAR_X moves to VAR_Y, so I do that (in the proper order to not mix things up).

```
data test_data;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
var_x=2;
var_y=3;
end;
do _iter = 1 to 7;
  var_z = 0.1+4*var_x+5*var_y;
  output;
  var_y=var_x;
  var_x=var_z;
end;
run;
proc print data=test_data;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this within a DO loop - the key is making SAS remember the last values of your variables. My suggestion is to poke around a bit for a simple "counter" program that, in pseudo SAS code, is something like:

```
Do i = 1 to 100;
   i = i + 1;
run;
```

And see what the actual syntax is in SAS. I suspect your problem is you're not using the *retain* statement within your DO loop. Check the SAS documentation for that and see if it fixes your problem?